# Sympletic matrix must have a determinant equal to one.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups

I hope that I am just confused, but I don't see why a sympletic map must have a determinant equal to one and not minus one?-Could anybody help me with that?- I am referring to the group

$$Sp = \{T \in GL(\mathbb{R}); TJT^T = J\},$$

where $J$ is the canonical matrix, see e.g. here [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymplecticGroup.html)

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is similar to Charlie Frohman's, but may also be helpful. The symplectic form determined by $J$ is the skew-symmetric bilinear map $\omega : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as $\omega(v,u) = v^{T}Ju$, and $(T^{*} \omega)(v,u) = \omega(Tv,Tu) = v^{T} T^{T}J Tu.$ So the condition you wrote above is exactly that $T^{*} \omega = \omega$. The symplectic form $\omega$ determines an orientation via its top exterior power $\omega^{n} = \omega \wedge ... \wedge \omega$, and  $T^{*} \omega^{n} = (T^{*}\omega)^{n} = \omega^n$. So $T^{*} \omega$ and $\omega$ determine the same orientation. Which is to say that if a collection $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ is positively oriented, then so is $Tv_{1}, ..., Tv_{n}$. Therefore, the symplectic transformations must preserve orientation. This is equivalent to saying that $\det(T) = 1$.